# if null or int(0) value to 0

Tags: comments

I am trying to get comment count. it works fine. but "0" value is not getting properly. it comes with empty or null.

```
    $comments_count     =  wp_count_comments(get_the_ID());
        $approved_comments_count = $comments_count->approved;
                        var_dump ($approved_comments_count);  //<=== this 

        if (($approved_comments_count===NULL) || is_null($approved_comments_count) || ($approved_comments_count === null ) || empty($approved_comments_count))
            $approved_comments_count=0;
```

I tested with "var_dump"

```
    string(1) "1"
    int(0)
    string(1) "1"
    string(1) "1"
    string(1) "2"
    string(1) "1"
    string(1) "4"
    int(0)
    int(0)
    int(0)
```

int(0) is not return to "0"

I added if condition, but not working. how can I make int(0) to "0"

Thank you,

Comment: _how can I make int(0) to "0"_ is already 0 what do you mean? Show the code where you are using it ?

Comment: it comes empty or blank... like this  ( http://prntscr.com/bkd6va ).. and it's ajax.. so it pass to js file ( http://prntscr.com/bkd8nh ).  this is the result page code.. ( http://prntscr.com/bkd76u )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no use for converting an integer to a string when you just need to display the result or for simple checking against a hardcoded known datatype value. Converting datatypes is only useful when you need to validate values strickly against a certain specific datatype.

Your issue is that you do not exactly know how to test your values. `0`, either an an integer or string value, constitutes as empty and null (*when loosely compared with`==`*) in PHP. If you need to check any variable if it is empty or having a value, including `0` as string or integer value, then you need to adjust your operators.

For you to specifically check and disallow/allow `0` as a valid/non-valid value, you need to use strick comparison, and here datatype counts. Just quickly `0 === "0"` will be false as integer `0` is not exactly the same as string `"0"`

Just a note here, your conditional statement is wrong and this is where everything fails. When checking `0` **strictly (`===`)** with `NULL` or `is_null`, the result will be false, and checking `0` with `empty()` will return true, which will execute your `||` operator in your conditional statement.

In your usecase, you can do the following to allow integer value `0` as a valid value and all other values, and disallow an empty string

```
if (    !$approved_comments_count // Universal check to see if empty, will consider false as empty too
     && 0 !== $approved_comments_count // Test for integer 0
) {
    echo '$approved_comments_count is a true empty string';
} else {
    echo 'The value of $approved_comments_count is ' . $approved_comments_count;
}
```

or even better

```
if (    $approved_comments_count // Allows anything that does not equal empty
     || 0 === $approved_comments_count // Test for integer 0
) {
    echo 'The value of $approved_comments_count is ' . $approved_comments_count;
} else {
    echo '$approved_comments_count is a true empty string;
}
```

If `0` where to be a string, you would test that `0` as follow

```
'0' === $approved_comments_count
```

or

```
"0" === $approved_comments_count
```

Comment: Sorry about this, I had an operator issue, recheck my code ;-)

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate for your detail description and pointing my wrong code ( I am not a senior dev. just learning now). 
I have found that it gets "0". ( http://prntscr.com/bkdp7o ). I am not sure if it's a string value or still and integer. it passes to ajax js. ( http://prntscr.com/bkdrao ) and... js file ( http://prntscr.com/bkd8nh ) and html result ( http://prntscr.com/bkd76u ).

I guess it gets well. the js file could be a problem to hide "0" value. I am not sure.  anyway very thank you for your time and detail info. it helps a lot

Comment: Solve, your tip was helped a lot. the problem was ajax js part. "data.amount_comments || 0 ); you saved my day. thanks!!